# LSTM Model not having any variance during evaluation

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I have a question regarding the evaluation of an LSTM Model. I have trained an LSTM Model and stored it with  `model.save(...)`. Now I want   `load_model` and evaluate it on the validation set datasets. Since neural networks are stochastic, I run it several times and compute the mean and the variance of the different metrics I am interested in.
Now I am shocked that after the first run all consecutive runs have the same performance on every metric. I don't think that is right, but I don't know where the error occurs.
So my question is:
what is my mistake in setting up the validation of my model?
and how can I fix that?

Here are the code snippets that should explain what I am doing:

Compile and fit the Model

```
def compile_and_fit(  hparams, 
                      MAX_EPOCHS, 
                      model_path ):
  
  
  window = WindowGenerator( input_width= hparams[HP_WINDOW_SIZE], 
                            label_width=hparams[HP_WINDOW_SIZE], shift=1,
                            label_columns=['q_MARI'], batch_size = hparams[HP_BATCH_SIZE])
  
  model =  tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(hparams[HP_NUM_UNITS], return_sequences=True,  name="LSTM_1"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(hparams[HP_DROPOUT], name="Dropout_1"),
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(hparams[HP_NUM_UNITS], return_sequences=True, name="LSTM_2"),
   tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))
])
  
  learning_rate = hparams[HP_LEARNING_RATE]
  model.compile(loss=tf.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
             optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate),
                metrics=get_metrics())

  history = model.fit(window.train, 
                      epochs=MAX_EPOCHS,
                      validation_data=window.val,
                      callbacks= get_callbacks(model_path))
  
  _, a,_,_,_,_ = model.evaluate(window.val)

  return a, model, history
```

Train and safe it

```
a, model, history =  compile_and_fit( hparams = hparams,                                                     MAX_EPOCHS = MAX_EPOCHS, model_path = run_path)
model.save(run_path)
```

Load and evaluate it

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(os.path.join(hparam_path, model_name),
      custom_objects={"max_error": max_error, "median_absolute_error": median_absolute_error, "rev_metric": rev_metric, "nse_metric": nse_metric})
model.compile(loss=tf.losses.MeanSquaredError(), optimizer="adam", metrics=get_metrics())
    metric_values = np.empty(shape = (nr_runs, len(metrics)), dtype=float)
for j in range(nr_runs):
  window = WindowGenerator(input_width= hparam_vals[i], label_width=hparam_vals[i], shift=1,
                      label_columns=['q_MARI'])
  metric_values[j]= np.array(model.evaluate(window.val))
means = metric_values.mean(axis=0)
varis = metric_values.var(axis=0)
print(f'means: {means}, varis: {varis}')
```

The results I am getting
[image: screenshots of the evaluation results]

For setting up the Training I follow those two guides:
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series
https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/hyperparameter_tuning_with_hparams

Comment: LSTM is not stochastic

Comment: If you save weights and then use those weights to predict data, you will get the same answer every time. The only thing that will be stochastic is your training process -- the act of generating the weights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LSTM is not stochastic. Evaluation results should be the same for the same data.

Comment: But then, why do the first and the second run of the evaluation give different results?

Answer (score 0):

There are two steps, when you train the model, randomness will influence the model you trained. However, after that, you saved the model, the prediction result would be same if you use the same model.